# C++ Delegated Constructors With Headers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, constructor, visual-studio-2012

**Delegated Construction Question:**
Compiler Error C2039: '{ctor}' is not a member of Logging::LogManager

I am using Microsoft's *C++ November 2012 CTP Compiler*, not the default one in Visual Studio 2012, so I have access to new C++ features, (variadic templates, etc).

I am trying to get delegated construction to work using namespaces and header files... I am not certain if this falls under the base constructor inheritance features yet to be implemented in Visual Studio 2012; so, it may be the case that I shouldn't expect this to work:

How do you do this in C++ 11?

```
// LogManager.h extract

namespace Logging {
    class LogManager
    { 
private:
            static std::wstring defaultFileName;
            explicit LogManager(std::wstring logFileName);
            explicit LogManager();
          ~LogManager(void);
}

// LogManager.cpp extract
/********************************************************************
*****/
Logging::LogManager::LogManager(std::wstring fileName)
{}

/********************************************************************
*****/
Logging::LogManager::LogManager()
    : LogManager(defaultFileName) // Yields C2664     
 // : Logging::LogManager::LogManager(defaultFileName) // Yields C2039
 // : Logging::LogManager(defaultFileName) // Yields C2614 

{}
```

error C2039: '{ctor}' : is not a member of 'Logging::LogManager'

error C2614: 'Logging::LogManager' : illegal member initialization: 'LogManager' is not a base or member

error C2664: 'Logging::LogManager::LogManager(const Logging::LogManager &)' : cannot 
convert parameter 2 from 'std::wstring' to 'const Logging::LogManager &'

**Answer::**
Cannot use explicit keyword in header file per known bug already known to Microsoft.

Only the first signature will work of the Constructor will work with this .. workaround.

Comment: Both clang and gcc accept this code. Could you remove VS error codes and replace them with descriptions? Also, **what the heck is [tag:c11] doing here?**

Comment: It should work (like the 3 version): See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14183972/14065 and it looks like VS2012 should support it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7422058/14065

Comment: @LokiAstari Are you saying you are able to do this?

Comment: @WindAndFlame: it is a bug (see my answer). Other compilers will handle this correctly, but not the compiler from the CTP.

Comment: @WindAndFlame: No. I don't have VS2012

Comment: @WindAndFlame, I meant the entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the CTP. It also shows up during [this presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/STLCCSeries6) by Stephan T. Lavavej (see from min 38:45).

The only possible workaround is to drop the `explicit` qualifier, if that's acceptable in your project. Otherwise, just avoid delegating to an explicit constructor.

In particular, this is *not* related to inherited constructors, which is a different feature and is not supported by the CTP (as Stephan T. Lavavej says in the same presentation I linked - just a few minutes after the bug occurs).

Comment: I saw that same video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/STLCCSeries6 ... Unfortunately, I had removed explicit as he recommended, and then put them back in when I couldn't figure out why I couldn't qualify my constructor name.  So answer:  No qualification & remove explicit works.  I have no idea if this lack of qualification will imply dubious things.  Thanks!